# eCryptFs: Unable to mount after password change in recovery mode

Tags: linux, mount, ecryptfs

I have reseted my user password using recovery mode.
Unfortunately after this operation I am unable to login into my account because my home directory is encrypted.

I can't mount my Private using `ecryptfs-mount-private` because it needs my previous password which I don't remember.

After many tries I was able to mount my Private using `ecryptfs-recover-private` and MOUNT passphrase. Thanks to this I have access to my files but still I am unable to login into my account (Private was mounted to temp directory).

Is there a way to change password used by ecryptfs-mount-private so I can normally login to my account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change your password you need to override `wrapped-passphrase` file which is located in `/home/_USER_/.ecryptfs`.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to start terminal and login into your account.

Type `ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase /home/_USER_/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`.
When you press enter you will see:
`Passphrase to wrap:` type here you `mount passphrase`. Next in `Wrapping passphrase:` type your current user password.

Now you can `exit` the terminal and go back to login screen by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. You should be able to login.